# Applying text-success to a Bootstrap 5 table row that is striped has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 table with the class table-striped. When the use clicks on a row, I have some jQuery code that toggles the class text-success on the row to highlight/unhighlight it.

The highlight works correctly on rows that do not have the striped background but has no effect on rows that do have a striped background.

This technique worked correctly on any row in the table when I was using Bootstrap 3.7

Here's some example code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">

</head>

<body>

<main class="container clearfix">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#mytable tbody tr").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("text-success")
    })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in bootstrap 5.1.2 and up there is this rule:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) > * {
    --bs-table-accent-bg: var(--bs-table-striped-bg);
    color: var(--bs-table-striped-color);
}
```

This selector above overrides in terms of specificity your selector, so you just need to make your more specific

**Note:** this is plan to be [fixed in v5.3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35158)

---

```js
//$("#mytable tbody tr > *").click(function() {
//  $(this).toggleClass("text-success")
//})

//arrow function version
//$("#mytable tbody tr > *").click(e => $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("text-success"))

//updated version - OP Comment - "Great, thanks. Is there a way to highlight the whole table row instead of just the column I click one?."

$("#mytable tbody tr > *").click(e => $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('td').toggleClass("text-success"))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container clearfix">
  <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Is there a way to highlight the whole table row instead of just the column I click one?.

Comment: Turns out that this fix complicates other parts of my application, plus it seem the Bootstrap folks are treating this as a bug to be fixed in 5.3, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35158.

The solution for me was to drop the use of table-striped and create my own css definition for nth-child(even) that sets the background color to a grey shade.  With that in place, no changes to my jquery codes is needed.

But thanks for the solution, I would not have been able to figure this out on my own.

Comment: can't understand why this solution would messed up other parts of your application but hey just a matter of time until v5.3 is released

Comment: I've updated the answer to match that info